# Populating nested fields using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have couple of collections: `rooms`, `messages` and `users`. Every `message` document has `room` property that is ObjectId reference of a room document and also has a `sender` property that references a `user` document. I am trying to get a single room with all of it's messages as well as the sender of every message. My current code looks like this:

```js
Room.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5ed4ffcdd13f45b4104a1669') },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'messages',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'room',
            as: 'messages',
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'messages.sender',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'messages.sender'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$messages.sender'
    },
    {
        $sort: { 'messages.createdAt': -1 },
    },
])
```

The above result returns only one `message` document only with the `sender` populated without other fields that the `message` document contains.

How can I populate the `sender` property of every single message when I return a `room` document`?

Comment: you probably need to add $unwind pipe between the lookups, because `messages` is an array

Comment: @molaga When I do an `$unwind` between lookups, it returns me an array of rooms each containing a messages array with a single message instead of one single room with an array of messages.

Comment: @J.Ivanovic, does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637505? You can use the pipeline version of `$lookup` to include another `$lookup`, Alternatively, you could use multiple `$unwind`s and `$group` them again

Comment: @thammada.ts Yeah that worked, thanks. :)